# SQL Merge Statements and should you use them

Tags: sql-server, merge, sql-update, sql-insert, sql-delete

I'm doing research into if and or when one can use Merge Statements.

I've had, many years ago, run into many different bugs that cause lots of errors or serious performance issues.

I've recently come to work at a new place and they use Merge Statements and its their standard practice.  I'm trying to find recent articles on if the bugs/concerns/performance have been resolved.

I've done some simple googling and there was an article that was last updated on 07-24-2018 talking about Merge on SQL Server.

It lists a long list of known issues and their last known status.

I have dived into them and it looks to be that there aren't any "major" bugs that would impact our workplace.

So, the question I have is:

**does Merge have good performance?**

Theoretically it should, but I can't find any articles or examples on it.

I'm looking for someone to explain to me or point me in the right direction on if SQL Merge Statements are now efficient and can be used as standard practice instead of the Insert/Update/Delete separate calls.

Comment: It's been a while, and my recollection is fuzzy here, hence just a comment. But if I remember rightly, the _main_ issue with merge was you still had to effectively write the complete test, insert, and update statements, and they still weren't guaranteed to be atomic between the check and the action. In other words, still just as much work for the developer as using the UPSERT pattern in a transaction, without the safety.

Comment: I remember there was a funny thing with the triggers being fired also. Merge statements tend to get hard to read for the programmer if they get complex. I'd recommend not using them and instead spliting into multiple operations inside a transaction.

Comment: The problem with `MERGE` is twofold, even after all the bugs are fixed: for the trivial cases it's still not as flexible and easy to read as separate statements in a transaction, and for the complicated cases just understanding the statements is tricky enough, let alone figuring out how to mitigate/solve any issues with locking. In theory `MERGE` is great, in practice it tends to introduce more problems than it actually solves. It has its uses (especially when combined with `OUTPUT`), but I'd definitely not recommend adopting it as "standard practice".

Comment: Aaron Bertrand wrote a [great article](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/) on this topic. It is a bit dated but many of the things have not or will not be fixed while some of the items listed have been fixed. It seemed so awesome when it was introduced but the syntax is so obtuse for even remotely complicated situations that I usually just do the standard update followed by an insert. It is so much easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

As someone who has used the merge statement extensively on a 2016 install I have found it works fine and produces very clean, easy to use, and maintainable code. I always make sure that columns that are used for matched and not matches cases are primary keys on the respective tables. When I am developing I use the 'output' clause aggressively to make sure that my logic is correct.